# Change all datatypes in a table

Tags: oracle-10g

I'm migrating a database and i need to change the "container", i don't exactly how to name it. I give an example to keep it clear :

*old base:*

```
VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
```

*new base:*

```
VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

I can do it individually with `alter...modify` query but it takes so much time to prepare the queries cause the tables have a hundred or more columns. Is there any scripting way or a query that changes all the **byte** containers with **char** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a bit of dynamic SQL.  Assuming that you want to modify every `VARCHAR2` column in one table

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT *
              FROM user_tab_columns
             WHERE data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
               AND table_name = <<table name>>
               AND char_used = 'B')
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 
       'ALTER TABLE <<table name>> MODIFY( ' || 
          c.column_name || ' VARCHAR2( ' || c.char_length || ' CHAR) )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You might want a `and char_length<>data_length` in your query so that you don't try and alter existing `VARCHAR2(XX CHAR)` columns.

Comment: @Phil - If there can be `xx char` columns, I'd prefer to use the `char_used` column.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Same end result. Cool

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks really nice. Could you tell how to execute it on SQL*PLUS or Oracle SQL developper cause i obtained the following error executing your query: Error in line 11 END LOOP
Error report:
Comand unknown

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez - I posted a snippet of PL/SQL, not a complete block.  I've updated my answer to be a complete anonymous PL/SQL block (though you'd obviously need to replace the <<table name>> with the actual table name.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i know i must replace the <<table_name>> with the name where i want to apply the method. But no how to create an entire PL/SQL block. Thanks for complete your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify multiple columns at once in the `modify` clause. For example, given:

```
create table modifyme
(
  col1 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  col2 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  col3 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  col4 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
);
```

You can execute:

```
alter table modifyme
modify
(
  col1 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  col2 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  col3 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
  col4 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
);
```

Easily scriptable using a similar technique to Justins.